# How to get the number of people you follow on twitter using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the number of people you follow on twitter without using the API. i.e. by scraping the information from the div. I've been scripting a userscript and I need to perform the scroll operation and set the Timeout value depending on the number of followers.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the API that was categorically and specifically designed to provide the functionality that you are asking for?

Comment: What page are you on then? The profile page or any page?

Comment: twitter.com/following

Comment: I'm learning JavaScript and just want to understand how it could be done :)

Comment: This question is getting more relevant now that the API isn't free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on your following page on Twitter (or any page with that following counter), you can find the number of people you follow with this expression:

```
$('strong','a[href="/following"]').text()
```

How does this work? Since Twitter has [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) enabled, you can use it to traverse the DOM easily. If you look through the page, you see the big blue number with the people you follow. That number is inside a link tag to the subpage `/following` and it can be found by the value of its `href` attribute. If you just use the text of the link tag, there might be `"Following"` in front of it. So just get the `<strong>` tag inside, with the actual number.

Comment: Yeah, I did that :) But i just couldn't do that on the [following page](http://twitter.com/following)

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation and another trick, should do it.

Comment: Yeah, had to get the text of the `<strong>` tag. You can mark my answer as accepted, so that other people know what's up.